# On the Connectedness of a Subspace of Product Space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected, product-space

I am struggling on solving the problem related to the connectedness of a topological space:

> Let $X$ be a countable product of a closed interval $[0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$, given the product topology. Prove or disprove that the space $ Z := X \setminus \{ ( 1, 1, 1, \cdots ) \}$ is connected.

I tried to solved this problem by showing that $Z$ is actually path-connected:

> Since the space $Z' := [0, 1]^2 \setminus \{(1, 1)\}$ is path-connected, for every point $x, y \in Z'$, there is a path $p =(p_1, p_2) : [0, 1] \to Z'$ such that $p(0) = x$ and $p(1)=y$. Now take two points ${\bf x} = (x_n), {\bf y} = (y_n) \in Z$. Consider the function $q : [0, 1] \to Z$ defined by
> $$
> q(t) = (p_1(t), p_2(t), p_3(t), \ldots )
> $$
> where the function $t \mapsto (p_1(t), p_2(t))$ is a path from $(x_1, x_2)$ to $(y_1, y_2)$ in $Z'$, and $p_j$ denotes the line segment from $x_j$ to $y_j$ for $j \geq 3$. Since each coordinate function of $q$ is continuous, so is $q$ since $Z$ is given the product topology. Hence $Z$ is path-connected, which implies the connectedness of $Z$.

My questions are,
(1) Is my trial correct? It looks like there is some ambiguous point in using the path in $Z'$; 
(2) Since the path-connectedness is more stronger property than the connectedness, I wonder whether there is an approach which is related only to the connectedness property, not the path-connectedness.

Comment: Note that it is possible for $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$ to be $(1,1)$, so they do not have to lie in $Z'$. Also, why do you make a different approach for the first two factors than for the others? Why can you not just take the line segment in every component?

Comment: Considering $Z'$ is pointless IMO. Just note that the standard path from $p$ to $q$ in $[0,1]^\omega$ can never go through $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ if $p$ and $q$ are not of that form.